# What's the best way to catch Firebase ajax errors?

Tags: firebase

I tried posting this in the Google Group as a statement and not a question but it didn't go through. :\

Firebase had some downtime the other night, and a call to `FirebaseAuthClient`'s `createUser` function was not going through, but its callback was not being called with an error.  In Chrome's dev tools, I could see that the underlying GET request was failing.

Can Firebase be updated so that all functions that rely on an ajax call return an error if the ajax call fails?

Answer (score 2):

[Engineer at Firebase] As you mentioned, we had some downtime in the past week that resulted in failed requests. While we're aiming to address this problem at the source, I think you're right, in that failed requests still throw an error on the client that can be programmatically handled appropriately. ~~I'll add this item to our internal tracker and push it live within the new few weeks.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the response.  I didn't mind the downtime in this particular instance, but thought this would be an important feature for the future.  Can't wait to see it.  Thanks for listening!

Comment: Has this been accomplished in the meanwhile?